# How to handle asynchronous callbacks in a synchronous way in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, architecture, integration-patterns

I have an architechture related question. This is a language independent question, but as I come from Java background, it will be easier for me if someone guides me in the Java way.

Basically, the middleware I'm writing communicates with a SOAP based third party service. The calls are async - in a way that, when a service is called, it returns with a response 01 - processing; meaning that the third party has successfully received the request. In the original SOAP request, one callback URL has to be submitted each time, where third party actually sends the result. So, calling a particular service doesn't actually return the result immediately; the result is received in a separate HTTP endpoint in the middleware.

Now in our frontend, we don't want to complicate the user experience. We want our users to call a middleware function (via menu items/buttons), and get the result immediately; and leave the dirty work to the middleware.

Please note that the middleware function (lets say X()) which was invoked from the front end and the middleware endpoint URL(lets call it Y)  where third party pushes the result are completely separate from each other. X() somehow has to wait and then fetch the result grabbed in Y and then return the result to the frontend.

[image]

How can I build a robust solution to achieve the above mentioned behavior?
The picture depicts my case perfectly. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How does the result-receiving middleware send the result to the original request target middleware? Are x() and y() different operations in the same service/application?

Comment: Futures and Promises.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: X() and Y() are all part of the same middleware. X() receives request from FE, and sends the async call to third party. Third party then processes the request and returns the result (can be a post call) to Y()(which is an endpoint URL - also in middleware)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question could be more about integration patterns than it is about multi-threading. But requests in the same application/JVM can be orchestrated using a combination of asynchronous invocation and the observer pattern:

This is better done using an example (exploiting your Java knowledge). Check the following simplistic components that try to replicate your scenario:

**The third-party service:** it exposes an operation that returns a correlation ID and starts the long-running execution

```
class ExternalService {
    public String send() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

**Your client-facing service:** It receives a request, calls the third-party service and then **waits** for the response after registering with the result receiver:

```
class RequestProcessor {
    public Object submitRequest() {
        String correlationId = new ExternalService().send();

        return new ResultReceiver().register(correlationId).join();
    }
}
```

**The result receiver:** It exposes an operation to the third-party service, and maintains an internal correlation registry:

```
class ResultReceiver {

    Map<String, CompletableFuture<Object>> subscribers;

    CompletableFuture<Object> register(String responseId) {
        CompletableFuture<Object> future = new CompletableFuture<Object>();
        this.subscribers.put(responseId, future);

        return future;
    }

    public void externalResponse(String responseId, Object result) {
        this.subscribers.get(responseId).complete(result);
    }
}
```

Futures, promises, call-backs are handy in this case. Synchronization is done by the initial request processor in order to force the execution to block for the client.

Now this can raise a number of issues that are not addressed in this simplistic class set. Some of these problems may be:

- race condition between `new ExternalService().send()` and `new ResultReceiver().register(correlationId)`. This is something that can be solved in `ResultReceiver` if it undestands that some responses can be very fast (2-way wait, so to say)
- Never-coming results: results can take too long or simply run into errors. These future APIs typically offer timeouts to force cancellation of the request. For example:

  ```
  new ResultReceiver().register(correlationId)
      .get(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

Comment: In your example, should `Map<String, CompletableFuture<Object>> subscribers` be initialized and static?

Comment: @gbdcool It surely has to be initialized, but doesn't need to be static (this depends on how the class is written. If, for example, it's a singleton (which I'd make it), the field doesn't need to be static).

Answer (score 2):

Well what exactly is the problem with doing that? You just create an API (middleware) which doesn't return response until the third party returns the processed result. Front end sends request to X(), X() processes that request by sending a request to Y() and then keep polling Y() to see when the result is ready, then X() takes  the results from Y() and sends it back to the front end. Like a facade.

There are some problems regarding using third party services that you don't control which you should consider. First of all you need to implement some kind of circuit breaker or timeout. Because the third party service might hang and never process the results (or process them so long that it makes no sense to wait). Also you should consider some meaningful way to keep the site running even if the third party service is not available or has updated their API or something else prevents you from using it.

And just one last thought in the end. Why would you want to make something that is already implemented asynchronous synchronous? It is made like that probably because it might take time. Blocking the front end for a long periods of time to wait for results makes the user experience unpleasant and the UI unresponsive. It is usually better to stick to asynchronous requests and show the users they are processing but let them do something else meanwhile.

Comment: I agree, making asynchronous calls synchronous doesn't sound right at first - but just think about it this way, not all the functionalities are gonna take forever to complete. Third party should have kept few sync calls for the simple tasks, which they haven't. So, why would we let our clients suffer for that? Some trivial tasks demand immediate responses - we can't actually show 'Your request is processing. Please wait' every time. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: Well that's what I said. It's like the facade design  pattern - simplify a more complex interface. You can do it but take some time to think about what would go wrong. For example at least add some timeout for these calls and return error if they don't complete in some reasonable time.

Comment: There's a problem though if I treat the async functionalities as it is - and I can't get my head around it. Suppose I let the front end call X() asynchronously. X() would then call third party, which returns with processing, and X() returns this to the frontEnd. meanwhile, 3party processes the result and returns it to Y. Now, nobody is listening to Y, x() has already returned the initial response to frontend. Some listener has to be introduced, so that Y returns the data to actual client. btw, by frontend, I mean mobile apps.

Comment: Yeah for mobile apps it is even better to make it with listeners and not block the interface. Because someone might think it crashed :) But yeah you will need to add some kind of listener or poll-ing after some time or keep some connection open for result in another thread or something